# What is the proper sudoers syntax to add a user?

Tags: sudo

According to the comments in `/etc/sudoers` (Fedora 13):

```
## Syntax:
##
##    user  MACHINE=COMMANDS
##
## The COMMANDS section may have other options added to it.
```

My two related questions:

1. What does the `ALL=(ALL) ALL` mean in the following line:

   ```
   root  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
   ```
2. I've tested these two lines but I cannot figure out how they are functionally different:

   ```
   superadm    ALL=(ALL)    ALL
   superadm    ALL=ALL
   ```

I've read the manual but the syntax specification is difficult to follow. I have derived that the `(ALL)    ALL` part is the command and tag specifications but I still cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Note:** I'm answering **1.**, since Ignacio [already answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18877/what-is-the-proper-sudoers-syntax-to-add-a-user/18878#18878) **2.**.

In the following `sudo` entry:

```
superadm  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

there are four fields:

- The first one specifies a user that will be granted privileges for some command(s).
- The second one is rarely used. It's a list of hostnames on which this sudo entry will be effective. On standard setups only one host is relevant (localhost) so this field is usually left as `ALL`.
- The *fourth* field is the list of commands `superadm` will be able to run with elevated privileges. `ALL` means all commands. Otherwise use a comma-separated list of commands.
- The third field (the one written `(…)` that is optional) specifies which users (and groups) the `superadm` user will be able to run the following commands as. `ALL` means they can choose anything (unrestricted). It this field is omitted, it means the same as `(root)`.

**Example:**

```
alan   ALL = (root, bin : operator, system) /bin/ls, /bin/kill
```

Here, `alan` is allowed to run the two commands `/bin/ls` and `/bin/kill` as `root` (or `bin`), possibly with additional `operator` or `system` groups privileges.

So `alan` may choose to run `ls` as the `bin` user and with `operator`'s group privileges like this:

```
sudo -u bin -g operator /bin/ls /whatever/directory
```

If `-u` is omitted, it's the same as `-u root`. If `-g` is omitted, no additional group privileges are granted.

Comment: Well, that's probably the best answer ever...

Comment: I observed that a newline `\n` character is mandatory at the end of the entry in sudoers or /etc/sudoers.d/your_file_name

Comment: Also you can use wildcards in host names, path names and command line arguments. Like `/bin/cat /var/log/messages.?` or `/bin/ls /var/log/*` more info [here](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html)

Comment: Just a little addition to this otherwise perfect answer: if there are multiple lines matching for a user in the sudoers-file, only the last match will be relevant. All other matches are ignored. This is something that can bite you in case you wonder why you do not get the privileges you just assigned yourself. In my case, it was the %admin group entry, that was much more restrictive than the one I created for my main user on my private machine. I kept wondering why the NOPASSWD entry I created for myself doesn't work and I still get asked the root-password every time I call sudo...

Answer (score 11):

From the `sudoers(5)` man page, **DESCRIPTION** section, **Runas_Spec** subsection:

> The first Runas_List indicates which users the command may be run as via `sudo`’s `-u` option.

...

> If no Runas_Spec is specified the command may be run as `root` and no group may be specified.

So there is no functional difference when trying to run commands as `root`, i.e., when not using `-u` with `sudo`. The difference matters when trying to run commands as other users; the latter will prevent this, but the former will allow it.