# What is the difference between these two sudoers lines?

Tags: sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper sudoers syntax to add a user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18877/what-is-the-proper-sudoers-syntax-to-add-a-user)

What is the difference between these two lines of /etc/sudoers:

- `USERNAME ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL`
- `USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

?

(To me when I have only ever used sudo as a convenience function. To me sudo is the same exact thing as doing: `su;EXECUTE_A_COMMAND;exit;` but sudo lets you do it in 1 line instead of 3. I have never used sudo for anything else... so I don't really understand the subtlety seen here.)